# Error Updating the WP8 SL app, CN mismatch

Tags: windows-phone-8, push-notification, windows-store-apps, msdn, mpns

Getting a error while updating an existing app(WP8SL app) in the store saying "There is a CN mismatch between the authenticated push notification certificate associated with your app and the one in this update". We using new MPNS certifcate for update.
Please help, do we need to change some thing in the app client code/manifest or in the certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Found the ans.

Below is a msdn forum link.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b1ebe4da-9eed-45bd-a82f-d32596998102/error-updating-the-wp8-sl-app-cn-mismatch?forum=wpdevelop